# How can I prevent all of my accodion components being toggled when clicked in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I created a custom Accordion component which again consist of two child components called `AccordionTitle` and `AccordionContent`:

The `AccordionTitle` component has a button. When clicked, the `AccordionContent` part toggles its style from `display:none` to `block` and back when clicked again.

**AccordionTitle.js**

```
class AccordionTitle extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.show = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;
    if (this.props.onToggled) this.props.onToggled(this.show);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.props.style}>
        <Button onClick={e => this.toggle(e)} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AccordionTitle;
```

**AccordionContent.js**

```
class AccordionContent extends Component {
  render() {
    let style = this.props.style ? this.props.style : {};
    style = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(style));
    style.display = this.props.show ? 'block' : 'none';

    return (
      <div style={style}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AccordionContent;
```

Also, I use the following parent component:

**Accordion.js**

```
class Accordion extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Accordion.Title = AccordionTitle;
Accordion.Content = AccordionContent;

export default Accordion;
```

Now, when I use the Accordion component, it's possible that I might need multiple accordions in a row which would look like this:

**ProductAccordion.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Accordion from '../Accordion/Accordion';

class ProductAccordion extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };
  }

  toggled() {
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show,
    });
  }

  render() {
    this.productsJsx = [];
    const products = this.props.products;

    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
      this.productsJsx.push(
        <Accordion.Title onToggled={e => this.toggled(e, this)}>
          {products[i].name}
          <img src="{products[i].imgsrc}" />
        </Accordion.Title>,
        <Accordion.Content show={this.state.show}>
          {products[i].name}<br />
          {products[i].grossprice} {products[i].currency}<br />
          <hr />
        </Accordion.Content>,
      );
    }

    return (
      <Accordion style={styles.container}>
        {this.productsJsx}
      </Accordion>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductAccordion;
```

As you can see, I am grabbing the `toggled` Event from `Accordion.Title` and I bind it to the prop `show` of `Accordion.Content` via the `toggled()` method.

Now, this works perfectly fine as long as there is just one product, but if there are more of them, clicking on the button will toggle all `AccordionContent` instances.

How can I change this so that only the content-part which belongs to the title that contains the clicked button will be toggled?

I also have the feeling that the component `Accordion` should take care of this (rather than `ProductAccordion`) by allowing `Accordion.Title` to delegate the `toggled` event directly to its sibling `Accordion.Content`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest storing the index of the open item in state, instead of a boolean. Then in your render, `show={this.state.show}` would be something like `show={this.state.show === i}`.

Full example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Accordion from '../Accordion/Accordion';

class ProductAccordion extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: null,
    };
  }

  toggled(event, ind) {
    const index = this.state.index;
    this.setState({ show:ind === index ? null : ind });
  }

  render() {
    this.productsJsx = [];
    const products = this.props.products;

    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
      this.productsJsx.push(
        <Accordion.Title onToggled={e => this.toggled(e, i)}>
          {products[i].name}
          <img src="{products[i].imgsrc}" />
        </Accordion.Title>,
        <Accordion.Content show={this.state.show === i}>
          {products[i].name}<br />
          {products[i].grossprice} {products[i].currency}<br />
          <hr />
        </Accordion.Content>,
      );
    }

    return (
      <Accordion style={styles.container}>
        {this.productsJsx}
      </Accordion>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductAccordion;
```

and this

```
class AccordionTitle extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.props.style}>
        <Button onClick={this.props.onToggled} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AccordionTitle;
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thanks! I also stored the previous state in `this.previous = ind` in `toggle()` and if both values are the same, I set `this.state.show = -1`, otherwise an already open element cannot be closed by clicking it again.

Comment: @Timo Excellent, glad I could help.